# How to use the MVP pattern in embedded systems?

Tags: design-patterns, embedded-systems, mvp

I am defining the architecture for an embedded system provided with an LCD touch screen for interacting with the user. To describe my problem I can use a washing machine provided with LCD touch screen as an example for my system.

Some of the user actions on the LCD are merely parameters change, like washing temperature, cycle type, etc. Other user actions on the LCD results in the triggering of a particular action. For example, pressing the start button triggers the beginning of the washing cycle.

In the process of defining the software architecture, I am evaluating the possibility to use the MVP pattern for implementing the interaction between the touch LCD screen and the washing cycle. Under this assumption, the View is represented by the touch LCD screen populated with various graphical widgets.

What is not clear to me is how to map Presenter and Model to my particular circumstances.

From my understanding, the model comprehends both behaviour and data. If this is correct, I believe that in my case the Model should be mapped to both washing cycle data and washing cycle logic. Whereas the Present role should be to coordinate LCD touch screen event, such as "Start button pressed", with the Model.

Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: Broadly, yes.  MVP is a UI pattern; not a pattern for your overall application architecture. The *Model* portion of MVP is everything unconcerned with UI activity; including application data, data validation, application logic (washing cycle logic in your case). The *Presenter* is your UI logic **for a specific view**, such as handling button presses, or deciding whether a button should be active for the user to press,   Note: There's typically a 1-to-1 relationship between Presenter/View.    On the other hand, the Model (being the "main application") tends to be shared across all presenters.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your interpretation is correct.

In the MVP patterns, the View is responsible for the (LCD) display, the Model for the actual washing machine and the Presentation layer is responsible for connecting the two together.

This means that the Presentation layer should

- retrieve the current values of the parameters for displaying them in the view
- update the values of parameters if the user has changed them
- translate button presses on the UI into an action for the washing machine.

Answer (score 0):

To quote from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653096/why-use-mvvm/20524980#20524980):

> <s>ViewModel</s> Presenter projects the data from the Model into a
>   format that fits the View.

The `Model` is the data in a way that makes sense to store the data. The `Model` knows the current washing state, has the ability to start/stop washing, can open the door, etc. The Model is also deciding when it will refuse to open the door. The `Model` doesn't know anything at all about the existence of a `View` or `Presenter`.

The `View` is the GUI logic that presents the data on screen. If there is no `Presenter`, the `View` knows about the `Model` and talks directly to the `Model`. If there is a `Presenter`, the `View` does not know about the `Model` and talks to the `Presenter` instead of the `Model`.

**The `Presenter` is the translation layer which allows you to keep the `View` simple.** The `Presenter`, just like the `Model`, does not know about the `View`. The `Presenter` is not strictly necessary: If the `Model` presents the data in a format that is trivial to display by the `View`, there is no need for a translation between them. But in real world projects there almost always comes a point where you do need a `Presenter`, because either the `Model` or the `View` change from the original design, making the originally trivial translation non-trivial.